# How to pass interface type/GUID reference to an automation method in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, automation

In Delphi you can pass class references around to compare the types of objects, and to instantiate them.  Can you do the same with interface references being passed to a COM automation server?

For example, you can define a method taking a GUID parameter using the type library editor:

```
function ChildNodesOfType(NodeType: TGUID): IMBNode; safecall;
```

In this function I would like to return automation types that support the interface specified by NodeType, e.g.

```
if Supports(SomeNode, NodeType) then
      result := SomeNode;
```

But the Supports call always fails, I tried passing in the Guids defined in the type library but none of the different types (Ixxx, Class_xxxx, IId_Ixxxx) seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *SysUtils* unit comes with at least five overloads of `Supports`, and they all accept a `TGUID` value for their second parameters.

You can indeed pass interface types as parameters, but they're really just GUIDs. That is, when a function expects a `TGUID` argument, you can pass it the interface type identifier, such as `IMBNode` or `IUnknown`. For that to work, though, the interface type needs to include a GUID in its declaration, like this:

```
type
  IMBNode = interface
    ['{GUID-goes-here}']
    // methods and properties
  end;
```

When the first parameter to `Supports` is an interface reference, the function calls its `QueryInterface` method. If it returns `S_OK`, then `Supports` return true; otherwise, it returns false. When the first parameter is an object reference, then it first calls the object's `GetInterface` method to get its `IUnknown` interface, and calls `Supports` on that like before. If it doesn't work that way, then it falls back to asking for the requested interface directly from `GetInterface`. If you've implemented `QueryInterface` correctly on your object, or if you've used the default implementation from `TInterfacedObject`, then everything should work fine.

If `Supports` never returns true for you, then you should revisit some assumptions. Are you *sure* your node really supports the interface you're requesting? Go make sure the class declaration includes that interface. Make sure `QueryInterface` is implemented properly. And make sure `SomeNode` actually refers to the node you're expecting it to.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks, great answer.  There was no reason that it shouldn't work, as I was using TInterfacedObject with no frills.  So I checked my assumptions and the failure was indeed a result of accidentally passing an object to Supports that didn't implement the interface.